# Kalman Filter's Correlation Formula

Tags: noise, autocorrelation, kalman-filters, random-process

I'm reading a book where the autocorrelation of white noise is expressed as:

[image]

What is the term $Q(k)$ and why is is expressed as an average value of a dot product ?

Comment: That's not an *average*, that's an *expectation* operator! Anyway, that's really a topic for a different day. $Q$ is probably just the covariance matrix, and it's likely defined somewhere around this?

Comment: $u(k)$ is a column vector and the resulting $Q(k)$ is a matrix rather than a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing your book is on Kalman filters and $u(k)$ is a term in a state variable equation of a linear system.  If so, it is a vector and the components of that vector at some time index $k$ can be correlated with each other but are independent with respect to $k$.

it isn’t a dot product, it is an outer product.